# Can't find wp-cron.php but I can see it in the public folder

Tags: wp-cron

I have a problem with the wp-cron.php file. I can see it when I browse the public folder and it has the permissions set to 755. But still I am getting this error in my server error log:

[Thu Mar 15 17:49:20 2012] [error] [client xx.xx.xxx.xxx] Couldn't find wp-cron.php, referer: http://secretsection.com/invizimals/?page_id=681

Can someone explain me why I get this error end what I can do to fix it?

BTW... I am using WP v. 3.3.1

BR

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but try to set this one in your wp-config.php

```
// make use of redirect rather than http loopback
define ( 'ALTERNATE_WP_CRON',   true );
```